# Regularity for solutions of $-\operatorname{div}(g(|\nabla u|^2)\nabla u)=f$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ and suppose that $g\in C^{1,\alpha}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, $f\in C^{0,\alpha}(U)$ for every open $U$ with $\overline{U}\subset\Omega$, $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $g\geq a$, where $a$ is a positive constant. Assume that $$-\operatorname{div}(g(|\nabla u|^2)\nabla u)=f,\ \mbox{in}\ \Omega$$

in the classical sense, where $u\in C^{1,\alpha}(U)$ for every $U$. Can I conclde that $u\in C^2(\Omega)$?

I was trying to solve this problem, by using Schauder Estimates, but I could not find anything specific. For example, if we call $g(|\nabla u(x)|^2)=h(x)$, then we have that

$$-\operatorname{div}(h(x)\nabla u)=f,\ \mbox{in}\ \Omega$$

with $h\in C^{0,\alpha}(U)$. Now I would like to use Schauder Regularity. Does anyonw knows any result in this direction?

Thank You.

Comment: Is there anything on the sign of $g'$ or at least its magnitude relative to that of $g$? Because I'm not sure you have ellipticity if you do not ....

Comment: @RayYang, suppose that we have ellipcity. I forgot to add this hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the ellipticity condition, take a look at Ladyzhenskaya and Uraltseva's book *Linear and Quasilinear Elliptic Equations*, Chapter 4, Theorem 6.3. It appears to provide what you need.

In case you do not have the book, basically your equation translates to 
$$g(|\nabla u|^2) \Delta u + 2 g'(|\nabla u|^2) \nabla u^T D^2 u \nabla u = 0$$
If you assume that $g$ is $C^{1,\alpha}$ and $u$ is as well, then the coefficients on every $u_{ij}$ are $C^{\alpha}$, treating the gradient terms as part of the coefficients, whence you can apply Schauder.

You do need to assume sufficient auxiliary conditions on $g'$ for the equation to be elliptic, however.